# Storing the value that meets a requirement in variable and finding the next value that also meets that requirement

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code that iterates through a list and if i % 10 equals 1, then I store that `i` in a variable. Then, I want my code to keep iterating through the list and if another i value meets the same requirement than it adds to a count.

This is what I have right now but it is just saving an i value and than adding to a count. This is because what I want to be my next i value is just the first i value that meets my requirement.

```
count 1_1 = 0
for i in B:
    if some_reqirement:
        if some_other_reqirement:
            if (old == 1) and (i % 10 == 1): 
                count1_1 += 1
            old = i % 10
```

Does anyone know how I could fix this?

EDIT:

this is the code with requirement, and I have tested the rest of the code and it works how i want it to.

A is a range with certain values replaced with with the value 1 and b is just a range.

```
count1_1 = 0    
for i in B:
    if B[i] % 10 == 1 and B[i + 2] % 10 == 3:
        if A[i] * A[i + 2] == 1:
            if (old == 1) and (i % 10 == 1): 
                count1_1 += 1
            old = i % 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still see `old` as essentially a boolean flag so let's make it one (called `previous_1`), but this time, instead of only being triggered True once, we'll change it's value based on every `i` that passes both requirements:

```
count1_1 = 0

previous_1 = False

for i in B:
    if B[i] % 10 == 1 and B[i + 2] % 10 == 3:
        if some_other_reqirement:
            current_1 = i % 10 == 1
            if current_1 and previous_1:
                    count1_1 += 1
            previous_1 = current_1
```

Comment: This helped helped a lot but it is slightly off of what I need. I need my function to only add to count1_1 if the next time that the first two requirements are met, at that point i %10 also needs to equal 1. What the code you wrote does though is it adds to count1_1 every time a new i value has remainder 1. Do you know a way that I could change it so that it works this way? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You're saving the old value too soon

```
    old = i % 10
    if (old == 1) and (i % 10 == 1): 
        count1_1 += 1
```

should be

```
        if (old == 1) and (i % 10 == 1): 
            count1_1 += 1 
        old = i % 10
```

or `old` and `i % 10` are identical: not what you want (since both expressions of your `if` test the same thing)

Comment: I tried that but when I ran the code it said this. local variable 'old' referenced before assignment

Comment: Define old = -1 at startup

Comment: Thanks for the help but this solution has the same problem as the problem to the last answer in this thread. if you read my comment to that question you will get what the problem is